# How to show surfaces as a implicit plot in 3d?

Tags: manipulate, plotting

I was trying to show a feasible region with these lines:

```
alfa = 0.75
RegionPlot3D[ x >= 0 && y >= 0 && z >= 0 && y <= 1 - alfa && z <= 1 - alfa && 
     x + y + z == 1, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}, 
     PlotPoints -> 40]
```

to then use Manipulate with `0<=alfa<=1`, but... I can´t view the region, and I know that for example `(1,0,0)` is a part of the feasible set.

How can I show  well that plot?

Comment: Hi, I translated "factible" as "feasible," which is the closest I could come up with.  Roll back if wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use `RegionFunction` in `Plot3D` instead of `RegionPlot3D`, like this

```
Manipulate[
 Plot3D[1 - x - y, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
  RegionFunction -> 
   Function[{x, y, z}, 
    x >= 0 && y >= 0 && z >= 0 && y <= 1 - alfa && z <= 1 - alfa], 
  PlotPoints -> 40, PerformanceGoal -> Quantity, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 1}}], {alfa, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

**Edit**

if the equations is not so simple, for example, x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == x + y, the evaluate will be more difficult, but it still works by using `Solve`, like this

```
f[x_, y_] = z /. Solve[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == x + y, z];
Manipulate[
 Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
  RegionFunction -> 
   Function[{x, y, z}, 
    x >= 0 && y >= 0 && z >= 0 && y <= 1 - alfa && z <= 1 - alfa], 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 1}}], {alfa, 0, 1}, 
 ContinuousAction -> False]
```

[image]

The speed of plotting will be a little slow, so I delete the `PlotPoints` assumption and add `ContinuousAction -> False`.

P.S. as an non-native speaker writing is very hard to me, so I prefer to use code instead sentences to show my idea, please excuse me:)

Comment: That´s a good solution but in this solution the user must define the graph as a function of other variables. What´s solution you propose in that cases where it´s more difficult or impossible to do.

Comment: I'm sorry that my English is very poor so that I didn't understood what you mean......You say "define the graph as a function of other variables", what does the "variables" mean? Some examples will be very helpful to me

Comment: My english is a little poor :-) but I refered that if the last constraint was more to dificult to extract any variable in function of other, the solution could be more difficult. Supose this conditions wher the last is different x >= 0 && y >= 0 && z >= 0 && y <= 1 - alfa && z <= 1 - alfa && 
 x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == x + y,

Comment: Oh I see, certainly it will be more difficult, but not too bad. I will edit my answer immediately.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem may be that you are trying to plot a region that is too thin (using the equality in the final condition). Allow the 3D region to have some small finite thickness and it seems to plot OK:

```
alfa = 0.25;
RegionPlot3D[x >= 0 && y >= 0 && z >= 0 && y <= 1 - alfa && z <= 1 - alfa && 
  Abs[x + y + z - 1] < 0.1, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

Now you can apply the Manipulate straightforwadly:

```
Manipulate[RegionPlot3D[x >= 0 && y >= 0 && z >= 0 && y <= 1 - alfa && z <= 1 - alfa && 
   Abs[x + y + z - 1] < 0.1, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, PlotPoints -> 100], {alfa, 0, 1}]
```